# Visual Studio Editor for Angular6

Tags: .net, angular, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017, angular6

I have read that VS Code editor has to be installed in order to work with angular.

My question is that whether we can use VS professional 2017 to work with angular.

Comment: "I have read that VS Code editor has to be installed in order to work with angular" - It doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to work with angular you need to install `Node npm`.
`VisualStudio Code` its enough and its perfect. Go to node.js website and download it, check it by `node -v`and `npm -v`
then you can run `npm` commands and install angular like this: 
`npm install -g @angular/cli` . The flag
`-g`make global to use whereever you want in your computer
Use VisualStudioCode or JetBrains

Comment: Last advice, use this extensions on VisualStudioCode: Bracket Pair Colorizer 2, GitLens — Git supercharged,
Material Theme,Todo Tree and vscode-icons. ENJOY